# Send a string in body via SendRequestAsync

Tags: c#, json, uwp, httpclient, win-universal-app

I need to send a Patch request to a backend API via SendRequestAsync func. This is regarding a UWP C# app.

Backend expected to like this:
[image]

On the app this is the code I wrote. But doesn't work

```
if (requestMehtod == ApplicationConstants.RequestType.PATCH)
            {
                Uri uri = new Uri(requestUrl);
                HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = null;
                if (postData != null)
                {
                    var itemAsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData);

                    requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Patch, uri)
                    {
                        Content = new HttpStringContent(itemAsJson, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8, "application/json-patch+json")
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Patch, uri);
                }

                response = await httpClient.SendRequestAsync(requestMessage).AsTask(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
                var rdModel = ProcessResponseData(response);
                return await Handle401Error(rdModel, response, postData, url, requestMehtod, isDownloadSite, OnSendRequestProgress, requestData);
            }
```

The above code fine to send JSON data to the same API and works fine. But I need to know how to send just a string in the body. Thank for the consideration

**NOTE: App uses HttpClient from Windows.Web.Http and will not be able to use anything inside System.Net.Http namespace.**

Comment: Instead of using a serialized json object for the stringcontent use a string...

Comment: Well, really that serialized json object is a string. Have you tried using the simple [ctor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpstringcontent.-ctor?view=winrt-19041) of the HttpStringContent class...`Content = new HttpStringContent("myString")`

Comment: Has your problem been solved? If it is not solved, please feel free to contact us.

Comment: @SimonWilson gave me the solution. Sorry I forgot to update the forum. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

The answer is given by the @gusman and @Simon Wilson. Just to amend to their answer, in order to be able to send a string in the request body, the string needs to be within double-quotes.

```
var requestData = "\"hello world\"";
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri)
                    {
                        Content = new HttpStringContent(requestData, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8, "application/json")
                    };
                    response = await httpClient.SendRequestAsync(request);
```

This worked in my scenario.

Comment: In fact, if you just pass a variable of type `string` instead of a complex type to `JsonConvert.Serialze`, it will do the same, what you have done manually, ie wrap the string with double quotes. Because that's what happens if you serialize a string to json